# Drop down menu with pure CSS when items have different height

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, height

There are several resources in the web describing how to implement slide-down menus, e. g. this:
http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/nicer-navigation-with-css-transitions-part-2
One problem one is facing is that CSS cannot animate the height to a destination of auto. Instead one has to use a fixed height like this:

```
.nav ul > li:hover ul li {
    height:36px;
}
```

which makes things complicated when the sub menus have different height and when additional menu items should be added easily.
Using max-height as described in the link above is not fully satisfying.
I know it can be done easily by JS/jQuery but I wonder if there is a clean way to make the height self adjusting by pure CSS.

Comment: Why can't you use `max-height`? Is there reason for `max-height` not being fully satisfying?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't satify me is that the sliding time is not constant when the height is differing. And the max-height needs manual adjusting in order to avoid some sub menu being cut off at the bottom.